# Structural Equation Models (SEM) what is the number of unknowns?

Tags: estimation, structural-equation-modeling

Lets consider the following vector-matrix equations from the LISREL model (indices indicate the format of the vector/matrix):

$$\eta_{n \times 1}=B_{m \times m}\eta_{m \times 1}+\Gamma_{m \times n}\xi_{n \times 1}+\zeta_{m \times 1}$$
$$Y_{p \times 1}=\Lambda_{y,(p \times m)}\eta_{m \times 1}+\varepsilon_{p \times 1}$$
$$X_{q \times 1}=\Lambda_{x,(q \times n)}\xi_{n \times 1}+\delta_{q \times 1}$$

The data given is the sample covariance matrix $S_{(p+q)\times(p+q)}$. Additionally we define $\Psi_{m \times m}=Cov(\zeta), \Phi_{n \times n}=Cov(\xi),\Theta_{\varepsilon,p\times p}=Cov(\varepsilon)$ and $\Theta_{\delta,q\times q}=Cov(\delta)$.

> **My question**: Is the number of unknowns $t$ equal to the following sum?
>   $$t= qn + pm + mn + mm+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+\frac{m(m+1)}{2}+\frac{p(p+1)}{2}+\frac{q(q+1)}{2}$$

So the necessary condition for Identfication is $t\leq \frac{(p+q)(p+q+1)}{2}$

Comment: Yes, I believe so. It's much easier if you consider all your variables to be y variables, and have no x variables though. (Most programs do this now - the original LISREL approach is more memory efficient, but we don't care about that any more).